# NSFetchedResultsController and table sections

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` and its delegate to populate a `tableview` with data coming from core data managed objects, [as described here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

However, I could not find a way yet to do something a bit different: I need my first section of the table to have some custom, static content, while the second section of the table should receive content `NSFetchedResultsController` objects array into its rows.

How can I specifically tell my `NSFetchedResultsController` to put everything it fetched into section 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your static content is simple enough, you could also stick it all into the header (instead of section 0).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
    // add labels, buttons, etc to header
    // ...
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than attempting to manipulate your data source, modify what you send to the `UITableView`. For example if it asks for the count of the sections, return 1 + the number of sections reported by your fetched results controller. If it asks for a cell just check if you're in section 0 and special-case it.

In general separation of duties under MVC means that your controller should be responsible for providing custom content rather than your model. Your model shouldn't have any knowledge of how its data should be presented. This way you can present the same data in multiple ways without hacking together an ugly solution.

Comment: I am actually taking care of this on the controller level, not on the model. Your solution worked for me but what I really needed is the answer below, the table header :). Maybe it was me not expressing correctly the question I had.